# How to get special price magento 2

Tags: mysql, magento

How can i add the special_price on magento.catalog_product_entity_decimal using joins.

attribute_id 77 = price and i need also special price attribute_id 78

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Subquery to get the result Here is the SQL Query you can use to get the data -

```sql
SELECT catprod.entity_id,catprod.value,catprod.value_id,catprod.store_id,catprod.attribute_id,(SELECT value FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` WHERE attribute_id=78 AND entity_id=catprod.entity_id) AS special_price FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS catprod WHERE `attribute_id` = 77;
```

[image: See Result Image]

The Above link show to data of price and special price in a row of products , those which are not having special price will be **NULL**.